# PHP: Changing notifiy.php from HTTP1.0 to 1.1 fails

Tags: php, http, paypal, notify

PayPal has mailed me that they will no longer support HTTP1.0 in a few days.

So i've changed my old PHP code:

```
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";  
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";  
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
```

to what they've recommended:

```
$header="POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .="Host: www.paypal.com\r\n"; 
$header .="Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
```

Now the notify.php don't work anymore :(

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: "Don't work" isn't good description of problem.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't provide an error message or something like that.

Comment: Why? And you can always describe why you think it's not working. Maybe it works? ;)

Comment: No it doesn't work, otherwise i would receive an email from my script :)

Answer (score 1):

Found this:

> PayPal recently announced that they're going to "discontinue support
>   for HTTP 1.0 protocol starting February 1, 2013."  Today I ran into
>   some problems implementing these changes.  It turns out that the
>   VERIFIED response code is now followed by a \r\n.  So, the previous if
>   (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) { code no longer works by itself.  I
>   was able to solve this by trimming off the \r\n using  $res =
>   trim($res);.

http://www.johnboy.com/blog/http-11-paypal-ipn-example-php-code